# How can i get cost of Azure resources grouped by location using az cli?

Tags: azure

I am trying to get cost of resources grouped by location using az cli :
What i want is to get for example all resources in my subscription "TestSubcription" and their cost grouped by location.

I currently have the following:

```
 az consumption usage list --query "[?type=='Usage'] | group_by([properties.instanceName, properties.instanceLocation]) | [].{Location: name, Cost: sum(properties.usageQuantity)}"
```

but i need to replace properties.instanceName and properties.instanceLocation , what would these for example be ?

Comment: you can add tags to the resources then filter by then

Comment: I have found that i can do it with the following:  az rest --method GET --url 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/UsageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01'   But this brings back a large  result. How can i group them by resourcelocation  ?

Comment: `az consumption usage list --scope /subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<your-resource-group-name> --group-by properties.instanceLocation --aggregate sum=properties.pretaxCost -o table` This will output a table with the location and the total cost of the resources in that location. Or do you absolutely want to use the —query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get cost of Azure resources grouped by location using az cli?

I do agree with @Niclas, alternatively, To get for specific location, I use below CLI command and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/usage?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az consumption usage list --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails']" --output json | jq 'group_by(.instanceLocation) | map({ Location: .[0].instanceLocation, Cost: map(.usageQuantity) | add })' | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.Location -eq "US East 2" }
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If need  `subscription`  then use :

```
az consumption usage list --subscription "test sub" --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails']" --output json | jq 'group_by(.instanceLocation) | map({ Location: .[0].instanceLocation, Cost: map(.usageQuantity) | add })' | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.Location -eq "US East 2" }
```

Comment: Gives an error: ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version

Comment: It did worked for me when I Used that command

Comment: I get an error with this :   ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version.

Comment: any ideas with this ?